# Tag Manager Cross Domain Tracking with Classic Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

Have a lot of client sites that use a similar system of their primary domain with an external checkout software hosted elsewhere. Their analytics is filled with self-referrals from the primary domain. For example.

I have a primary domain in which I have entire control. This has a Google Tag Manager implementation using Universal Analytics. The secondary domain, a booking system, uses classic analytics.

I have no control over how the analytics on the booking system is implemented (aside from setting the tracking ID), but the developers say it is setup to use cross-domain tracking. Their implementation has:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-67867867-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.seconddomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/properties/abcd']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_cookiePathCopy', '/reservations/abcd/']);
```

My understanding is I need to configure GTM to mirror these settings as per the "Inconsistent Tracking Code Configuration" directions at: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en

In GTM, "Allow Linker" is set to true. "Auto Link Domains" has "primarydomain.com, seconddomain.com", but this seems pointless as GTM is not on the second domain. "Cookie Domain" is auto.

Self-referrals still happen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the cross domain implementations in analytics.js and ga.js are incompatible with each other.  The booking system will need to upgrade to analytics.js (or you will need to downgrade to ga.js).

To get rid of referrals from the booking system, follow these instructions: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830

Comment: Ah, I will test that! Is there any documentation mentioning the incompatibility? I did setup referral exclusions, but it was ignored possibly due to the poor setup of having analytics.js and ga.js.